# Why does zero times zero equal zero?

Tags: arithmetic

When trying to prove that if $mx = 0$, $x = 0$, I had to assume that $m \neq 0$.

In the case that $m = 0$, then $0 * 0 = 0$.

However, it's not clear that $0 * 0 = 0$. Or is it supposed to be?

Comment: How to prove a statement like this depends heavily on what facts you are allowed to assume.  What is your context?  How are $0$ and multiplication defined for you?  (Or are they axiomatized, rather than defined?)

Comment: I'm not sure how this doesn't meet the m.SE guidelines. This is a math question where $0 * 0$ is unclear! Eric, you are correct that I should have assumed a system of arithmetic. The edits reflect that.

Comment: @EricWofsey Read above.

Comment: Still awaiting a reply or un-close vote from @EricWofsey.

Comment: "A system of arithmetic" does not clarify much of anything: *what* system of arithmetic?  I just guessed at a tag since your original tags were completely inappropriate, but it is still very unclear what the correct tags would be for the context you intend.  (Plausible alternative tags would include abstract-algebra and real-analysis.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the definition of $0$. A zero, $0$, is a number such that $0+x=x$ for all $x$. But then we have
$$
0 \cdot x= 0 \cdot (x+0)= 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot 0
$$
Using additive cancellation, i.e. subtracting $0 \cdot x$ from both sides, we find that $0 \cdot 0 = 0$.

EDIT. We can extend this to
$$
0 \cdot x = (0+0) \cdot x = 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x
$$
to show that $0 \cdot x= 0$ for any number $x$ by instead subtracting $0 \cdot x$ from both sides.

Answer (score 0):

The reason we have to assume $m \neq 0$ in the proof you mentioned is that if $m=0$ then $x$ is not necessarily $0$, though it still can be.

i.e. $x=1, m=0$ still gives you $mx=0$.

We have to assume $m\neq 0$ not because $0\cdot 0 \neq 0$ (which is not true anyway), but because without $m \neq 0$, it is not a sufficient condition to reach the conclusion $x=0$